# ListView's Item longClick not working with ImageView(Clickable)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a `listView` with items that contains `textview` and `imageView` (when clicking on `imageView` it should show fullScreen image), and when longPressing any item, then should show a popup.

All things are working fine until I try to longClick using `imageView`. because when I put touch on `ImageView` , `listView's` longClick method not getting called, and after pulling touch, `imageView's` click get called.

And I want it to be like that :

When longClicking on `imageView`/`listItem`, it should show only alert and on single click on `imageView` it should show fullScreen image.

Please help me with any suggestions.

Comment: Try to put the `onLongClick` event to the `imageView` in adapter.

Comment: I don't want to perform task on longClick on imageView.

Comment: i had same issue. i used gesture listener library of Android to handle click, long click, tap and double tap on different child of same layout.

Comment: can you please post some example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I've found solution for this issue :

I needed to return **"true"** in longClickListener.
like :

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("debug", "onLongClick = " + i + "  " + view.getTag());
        return true;
    }
});
```

And needed to add following line in item_view.xml :

for superParent layout add line :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

for that imageView :

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had this same problem. Textview in a listview, setting textview to `android:longClickable="true"` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Attach same `OnLongClickListener` to the `ImageView` and the `listitem`. If this doesn't work you could also assign your long click listener to the outermost (parent) element of your item view instead.

Comment: outermost (parent) has already longClickListener. But i think this is not a valid solution, means if I want to add more views that are clickable then I will need to add longClickListener for all of them..

Comment: @NehaK Why exactly do you consider it an invalid solution?

Comment: not invalid but kind of improper solution.. I need some like TouchIntercept layout kind of solution..

Comment: @NehaK could you try to rephrase your question then, because the way it's now, my answer is correct.

Comment: @ Karsen Gauss , I've added solution, please check. Thanks for your try :)

Comment: How can your answer is right, you said i should add OnLongClickListener for imageView also..

Comment: Downvoting an correct answer to your question is not cool. Next time make sure you state your question precisely, preferably with code samples, to make sure you get answers you want.

Comment: I've already stated my question precisely, yes I haven't added code.. but I don't think there is need to add any code..

Answer (score -1):

Because in listview item only one click event work if you add on imageview click event so listview click event not work because listview consider imageview as list raw item so that time only one click event is work either imageview click event otherwise listview click event.

Comment: I know this.. but isn't there any solution for this?